# Rails fields for- receiving array from text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms

I have a `form_for`, and a nested `fields_for` within it.

now it looks like this

```
form_for blah 
  fields_for :badgetype do |b|
    b.text_field :name
    b.text_field :keyword
```

Params looks like `badgetype: { :name => "foo", :keyword => "bar" }`

What I want is to have 5 of these set up, and get something like this back:

```
badgetype: { 1 => { :name => "foo", :keyword => "bar" }, 
             2 => { :name => "boof", :keyword => "baz" },
             ... 
           }
```

How would I accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
<%= form_for blah do |a| %>
  <% (1..5).each do |number| %>
    <%= a.fields_for "badgetype[#{number}]" do |b| %>
      <%= b.text_field :name %>
      <%= b.text_field :keyword %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= a.submit %>
<% end %>
```